# Android studio 2.3 canary missing 'Launch Standalone SDK Manager' option in 'SDK Manager'

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager, android-studio-2.3

I inadvertently accepted android studio's upgrade suggestion to 2.3 (canary), although I had always had it set to check for the developer channel, not canary, somehow that got switched. Now I no longer have a 'Launch Standalone SDK Manager' option in my 'SDK Manager' window.

I liked the standalone manager for various reasons, including that it suggested what needed to be downloaded and upgraded. The regular sdk manager lists a lot of things I expect I don't need like 'CMake', 'LLDB', 'Constraint Layout for Android', 'Solver for ConstraintLayout', 'Google Play APK Expansion Library' ('Google Play APK Expansion Library rev 3' is already installed, so do I need this too?), etc.

Is the standalone sdk manager unavailable for 2.3 canary 2, or is there something more I need to do to get it?

Comment: Google has been trying to kill off the standalone SDK Manager for months. Do not be surprised if it goes away entirely in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: @CommonsWare Any reasoning for that?

Comment: I don't think that they want to maintain it.

Comment: Yes it's very true, they removed it in 2.3 stable !!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also have updated to the Canary version 2.3 and I'm amazed that they took it away there.. but you can still start it via the `SDK Manager.exe` located in your sdk folder

```
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Comment: Just updated to Android Studio 2.3 and the standalone SDK Manager doesn't start anymore. Can anyone else confirm this? After reinstalling the SDK tools ,the SDK Manager is gone... RIP

Comment: @myfknoll follow the path given in the answer in My Computer and start SDK manager from there.

Comment: How can i run in Ubuntu?

Comment: @myfknoll Glad I could help ! perhaps you can flag or upvote my comment so that other users can see the flag and act accordingly :)

Comment: @JaiminThakkar and SanjayBhalani you can use this in your terminal cd /home/Android/Sdk/tools and then use ./android to start android SDK manager.

Comment: Hi, Murat K. i have tried this but open like a blink and gone

Comment: I also have similar experience that Standalone SDK Manager is gone with Android 2.3. I am unable to launch the Standalone SDK Manager at sdk or sdk\tools (Android 2.3 SDK Manager is working fine though, just Standalone fails to launch). Looking at sdk\tools\android.bat indicates that "The 'Android' command is no longer available. For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio. For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat". *In a nutshell, the Standalone SDK Manager is now RIP with Android 2.3.*

Answer (score 7):

**Present:**Today when i was trying to launch, the terminal says,
                                           The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
**Past:**
I also face the problem after updating to Canary version 2.3 on my mac.. On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the location where the Android SDK is installed, then execute **android sdk**
or for only mac user go to folder located in 
`/Users/your mac account name/Library/Android/sdk/tools`
and double click **android** to Launch Standalone SDK Manager

**My Advice:** Stop Searching for **Launch Standalone SDK Manager** and get use to be of android studio SDK manager and just choose the **Show Package Details** for more detailed description like **Launch Standalone SDK Manager.**

Answer (score 3):

[image]Yes, "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" option in Android Studio V2.3 is not available, But you can still start it via SDK Manager.exe located in your sdk folder.

**c:\Users\You_User_Account_Name\AppData\Local\Android\SDK Manager.exe**

Enjoy Android Studio with new features.

Comment: @MKY, As I update my post with Image representation hope this will help you.(AppData is hidden folder so Unhide it from control panel/folder option )

Comment: I have removed my vote down. thanks for detail answer.

Comment: Thanks @MKY, if you found the answer correct please accept as you found your answer.

Comment: IT DOESN'T EXIST. PERIOD. NOT THERE. NOT ANYWHERE ON HARD DRIVE.

Answer (score 3):

With the 2.3 Canary update, when using `SDK Manager.exe` or `tools/android.bat`, no manager is opened. However `tools/android.bat` give a pretty good answer to why it is not working:

`The "android" command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use
tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat`

We can still use command-line tools, but no more standalone SDK manager.

Comment: What @MatthieuNogueron mentioned, "*We can still use command-line tools, but no more standalone SDK manager.*" is what I am experiencing. Goodbye Standalone SDK Manager. We will miss you.

Answer (score 1):

I just received an official response from AOSP - 
Project Member #1 uchid...@google.com
deprecated feature , please check latest stable version Android 2.3

The link is now gone, and it is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the standalone sdk manager option is missing in Android Studio 2.3. Get yourself used to the sdk manager available in Android Studio settings.

 Also if you are installing Android Studio from scratch, you will not be available to find `Sdk Manager.exe` from `C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` or anywhere you install it.