# Failed to get the required ADT version number from the

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Yesterday I tried to install ADT plugin to Eclipse, but when I restarted it I found the next screen:

[image: Error]

When I click on "Open SDK Manager", I see something loading but after waiting it doesn't open anything:

[image: Loading]

After that this dialogue closes and I don't see anything else of Android

PS: Ignore the code behind.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you upgrade Android Studio to 2.3?
*in console D:\Programas\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\tools\traceview.bat* 
This error is caused by the lack of [traceview.bat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwhcYOlyJN-Pb0lfTnNIQVlXQm8) files,download [traceview.bat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwhcYOlyJN-Pb0lfTnNIQVlXQm8),and places to the file into your SDK\tools

Comment: It doesnt solve the issue of getting the message of the "failed getting required sdk version", but at least the app can now run after adding the file

Answer (score 34):

Please download a new SDK for Eclipse，Android Studio use another.
Hope to help you！

See [Eclipse: Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK](https://my.oschina.net/XngPro/blog/869548)

### Download Old Version SDK

- https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe
- https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip
- https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip
- https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

Comment: I did and ir worked I changed muy SDK location yo one diferent oh android studio SDK. Thanks

Comment: Where can I find the latest SDK that works with Eclipse?

Comment: two sdk's for both?

Answer (score 16):

1. Download earlier version of SDK tools (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r24.4.1-windows.zip). Replace suffix -windows with -macosx or -linux to get packages for other platforms.
2. Unpack to *sdk-eclipse* directory, you'll have following directory structure *sdk-eclipse/tools/* .
3. Run android.bat from tools directory and download required platforms and build tools. Be careful NOT TO UPDATE SDK TOOLS!
4. Change Android SDK directory in Eclipse (Windows->Preferences->Android, SDK Location) to your new directory "sdk-eclipse".

Comment: Is that the latest sdk that still works as it is with Eclipse? And can you still update the sdk itself, just not the build tools?

Answer (score 5):

1.Download the sdk file from this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9FT-4TSz8ukYnJWQ3hJUmYyQzA).

2.Unzip it.

3.Place this two file into: `/Users/computer_name/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/` or you can place it your desire place.

4. Then open eclipse IDE.
5. Go to the **Windows->preferences->change the sdk location**.
6. And place the location where the sdk located.
   Example: if you store those two file in `/Users/computer_name/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/` the set the location -> `/Users/computer_name/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/sdk`.

note:Here *sdk/sdk* because you store downloaded two file - sdk file & SDK Manager into the sdk file.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I'm sure the community appreciate your providing a packaged version of the Android SDK that works with Eclipse.  I would do just about anything to be able to continue using the very powerful environment of Eclipse for my Android developments.  But it's important to advise the users to beware of downloading personal packaged software from users. (continued)...

Comment: ...(continued)  If you didn't modify the SDK package and could provide a link or a method of finding (or compiling) from an official source it would be helpful and a less risky resolution. I make this comment because I understand (just as it was when I was new) that many novice users look at the answers on SE as information endorsed by the community.  They might not realize they should at least check the user's rep on the site and review other accepted answers the user have provided.

Comment: @Sadia Thanks its working could you please tell me what has happened before. what was the root cause?

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this issues by a few steps:

> Download this:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.1-windows.zip

Then go to your SDK folder path. in my case my android SDK are stored here:

```
C:\Users\[COMPUTER NAME]\android-sdks\
```

Rename `"tools"` to `"tools backup"`

Extract the ***tools_r25.2.1-windows.zip***, copy and put into the android SDK folder

Restart the Eclipse

Caused: The tools file can be changed if you install latest Android studio

Answer (score 4):

You can download your adt from **Eclipse Marketplace** or **Install New Software**  otherwise you can also specify the adt **installed directory**.

Here we are going to see about the **Eclipse Marketplace**.

Select **Help-> Eclipse Marketplace**

and then type **adt** and  then install the adt plugin.
[image]

Comment: Dude... now I see the message two times https://gyazo.com/2d4665d791ebe64aa28f7612e3f1f522 in both i have the same result clicking on "Open SDK Manager"

Comment: I see this in console:
_[2017-03-10 12:02:43 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: D:\Programas\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\tools\traceview.bat_

Comment: Restart your system and try again. If the same error shown. Your sdk location must be changed. In Strange case Disk have no space to store the plugin.

Comment: The store is not a problem, I restarted the system twice, i think you are right to change the sdk location, how can i do this?

Comment: **Select Window->Preference->Android> Sdk Location**  and then change you Directory

Comment: do you think that if I configure the SDK manager from Android studio it could work with eclipse?.
I changed the SDK location and I still the same message

Comment: Solved, i changed the sdk location, i used other sdk

Comment: Where did you find the "other sdk"? I tried copying/pasting but it didn't work. Do I have to install it again? Where can I find the sdk to be installed? It seems like now it always comes with Android Studio, both together.

Comment: You can Download the sdk form  https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html

Comment: Where can I find the latest SDK that works with Eclipse? That link contains versions only as far as 2009

Answer (score 1):

The executable file of SDK Manager is disappeared in the sdk path, I guess it was removed forcefully by Google.

see also:

- [Standalone SDK Manager option in Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577166/standalone-sdk-manager-option-in-android-studio-2-3)
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235625

By the way, Eclipse shows the error in the console view when I run a project:

```
[2017-03-16 15:40:53 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: /Users/MyName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/traceview
```

There may be a solution to find the SDK Manager.exe for windows users, see: [Android studio 2.3 canary missing 'Launch Standalone SDK Manager' option in 'SDK Manager'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891862/android-studio-2-3-canary-missing-launch-standalone-sdk-manager-option-in-sdk) , but for the Linux base users, I have no idea...

Could any one help resolve it in the Mac?

Comment: Where can I find the latest SDK that works with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the same SDK location for Eclipse and Android Studio, Please try to not do this, because it's will create some errors !!

 I hope this advice helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use the device emulators in Eclipse, instead of duplicating the Android Studio SDK directory, you can simply create symbolic links from the new Eclipse directory to the old one for all the subdirectories except `tools/`, then in the Eclipse SDK directory extract the v25.2.0 of the tools.

More in detail, for Linux/MacOS:

1) given the existing SDK directory in `$TOPDIR/android-sdk` used by Android Studio,

2) create a new empty directory `$TOPDIR/android-sdk-eclipse`

```
$ cd $TOPDIR
$ mkdir android-sdk-eclipse
```

3) for each directory in 1) except `tools`:

```
$ ls -al $TOPDIR/android-sdk
...
drwxrwxr-x  3 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 ott 19  2016 add-ons
drwxrwxr-x  9 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 dic  1 13:58 build-tools
drwxrwxr-x 21 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 ott 26  2016 docs
drwxrwxr-x  7 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 gen  8 14:49 emulator
drwxrwxr-x  5 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 feb 23  2017 extras
drwxrwxr-x  3 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 ott 23 17:05 fonts
-rw-rw-r--  1 xxxuser xxxuser   16 gen  8 15:26 .knownPackages
drwxrwxr-x  2 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 feb 15  2017 licenses
drwxrwxr-x  3 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 lug 21 11:48 lldb
drwxrwxr-x 12 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 dic 14 12:15 ndk-bundle
drwxrwxr-x  4 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 feb 15  2017 patcher
drwxrwxr-x 23 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 dic  4 14:10 platforms
drwxrwxr-x  5 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 gen  8 14:49 platform-tools
drwxrwxr-x 23 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 dic 12 13:17 skins
drwxrwxr-x  5 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 nov 23 14:16 sources
drwxrwxr-x 12 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 dic 21 13:52 system-images
drwxrwxr-x  2 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 dic 14  2016 temp
drwxrwxr-x  6 xxxuser xxxuser 4096 set 22 10:21 tools
```

create a symbolic link in directory 2):

```
$ cd $TOPDIR/android-sdk-eclipse
$ ln -s ../android-sdk/add-ons .
...
$ ln -s ../android-sdk/temp .
```

3) download the file https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip (replace linux with macosx or even windows for other platforms)
in the directory 2) and unzip it:

```
$ unzip tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip
```

4) eventually the directory 2) will have the following content:

```
$ ls $TOPDIR/android-sdk-eclipse
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        22 gen  8 15:13 add-ons -> ../android-sdk/add-ons
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        26 gen  8 15:13 build-tools -> ../android-sdk/build-tools
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        19 gen  8 15:13 docs -> ../android-sdk/docs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        23 gen  8 15:13 emulator -> ../android-sdk/emulator
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        21 gen  8 15:13 extras -> ../android-sdk/extras
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        20 gen  8 15:13 fonts -> ../android-sdk/fonts
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        23 gen  8 15:13 licenses -> ../android-sdk/licenses
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        19 gen  8 15:13 lldb -> ../android-sdk/lldb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        25 gen  8 15:13 ndk-bundle -> ../android-sdk/ndk-bundle
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        22 gen  8 15:13 patcher -> ../android-sdk/patcher
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        24 gen  8 15:13 platforms -> ../android-sdk/platforms
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        29 gen  8 15:13 platform-tools -> ../android-sdk/platform-tools
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        20 gen  8 15:13 skins -> ../android-sdk/skins
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        22 gen  8 15:13 sources -> ../android-sdk/sources
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        29 gen  8 15:15 system-images -> ../android-sdk/system-images/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxxuser xxxuser        19 gen  8 15:13 temp -> ../android-sdk/temp
drwxr-xr-x 12 xxxuser xxxuser      4096 dic 13  2016 tools
-rw-rw-r--  1 xxxuser xxxuser 277894900 ago 24 17:31 tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip
```

(to save disk space you can remove the file `tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip` once unzipped).

5) set the new directory as the ADT directory in Eclipse: `Windows -> Preferences -> Android`, change the field `"SDK Location"` to the new directory path `$TOPDIR/android-sdk-eclipse`(expand the `TOPDIR` placeholder)

This will save 100s of MB on your hard disk, at the same time keeping different tools versions for Android Studio and Eclipse.

The only caveat AFAIK is that the device emulator won't work when launched from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Eclipse 2019-12 and got the same message about the ADT version number. I added the traceview.bat file, but it did not do anything.

Then I did what I have done in the past with e.g. Visual Studio, in order to overcome various warning messages. I opened Eclipse **as Administrator** and it worked. It did not bring up the warning message.